# Generate D3 Pie Chart of api data

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, d3.js

I am trying to create a D3 Pie Chart with data of an API.

The problem is that after the 'return' in .value of `d3.layout.pie` it will not generate the Pie with the different arrays (more than one array at least).

I want all the count_downloads(arrays in different slices. The jsondata.uploads.length contains 50 array (or numbers). The data looks (in the console) like this: [10, 2, 34, 29, 57, 30, 35].

`dataExample.json` is just a placeholder, since that data is coming from the api.

Thanks!

```
(function() {  

  var app = angular.module('nounTranslate', []);
  var json

  app.controller('apiController', function(){

    var request_data = {
        url: 'oath.php',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
          term: 'beer',
          site: 'http://api.thenounproject.com/'
        } 
    };

    var array = []

    $.ajax({
        url: request_data.url,
        type: request_data.method,
        data: request_data.data,
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(jsondata) {

        // HIER KOMT DE API DATA BINNEN  

        //nieuwe (json)data zodat het niet conflict raakt 
        json = jsondata;

        d3.json("dataExample.json", function (data) {   

          setTimeout(function() {

          }, 600);  

          for(i=0;i<jsondata.uploads.length;i++){

            jsonArrays = jsondata.uploads[i].count_download
            array.push(jsonArrays);  

            // console.log(array);

            var pie = d3.layout.pie()
              .padAngle(.02) // Ruimte tussen de arcs
              .value(function(d) { // Vormt de data om naar de layout van de pie chart 
                  console.log(array);
                  return parseInt(array);
              })
          }

          var body = d3.select("body");
          var div = body.append("div")  
              .attr("id","chart")
              .attr("class","chart")

          // De omvang van de donut chart
          var width = 260,
              height = 260;

          // Maakt de donut chart rond   
          var outerRadius = height / 2 - 10,
              innerRadius = outerRadius / 2,
              cornerRadius = 10;
              colors = d3.scale.category20c(); // Gebruikt een preset aan matchende kleuren

          //Geeft eigenschappen mee aan de arc (boog) vorm
          var arc = d3.svg.arc()
              .padRadius(outerRadius)
              .innerRadius(innerRadius);

          //Informatie weergaven arcs    
          var infoHover = d3.select('#chart').append('div')
              .style('position', 'absolute')
              .style('padding', '0 25px')
              .style('opacity', 0)


          //Functie: veranderd hoogte - (outer)radius arc in een animatie     
          function arcTween(outerRadius, delay) {
            return function() {
              d3.select(this).transition().delay(delay).attrTween("d", function(d) {
                var i = d3.interpolate(d.outerRadius, outerRadius);
                return function(t) { d.outerRadius = i(t); return arc(d); };
              });
            };
          }

          //Plaats de chart in de div 
          var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
              .data(data)
              .attr("width", width)
              .attr("height", height)
            .append("g")
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")") //Positie chart
            .selectAll('path').data(pie(data)) // Selecteerd onderstaand path, gebruikt pie layout en de data
            .enter().append('path')
              .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
                  return colors(i); // Voeg de kleuren (category20c) toe bij alle data: index
              })
              .each(function(d) { d.outerRadius = outerRadius - 20; })
              .attr('d', arc) // Maakt de arc (buitenste cirkel)
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.  `parseInt(array)` isn't valid JavaScript.  Did you want to sum all the values in the array for a single slice?  Or do you have an array of data where each `count_download` is a pie slice?  Showing us what `dataExample.json` contains would help a lot...

Comment: I want all the count_downloads in different slices. The jsondata.uploads.length contains 50 array (or numbers).

The data looks (in the console) like this:

[10, 2, 34, 29, 57, 30, 35] 

`dataExample.json` is just an placeholder, since that data is coming from the api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are asking.

With `d3`, you don't explicitly loop your data.  You bind your array and it draws based on the contents of the array.  In your case, you would bind your array:

```
.selectAll('path').data(pie(jsondata.uploads)) // Selecteerd onderstaand path, gebruikt pie layout en de data
```

And then give it a value function to return the piece you want to plot:

```
 var pie = d3.layout.pie()
     .padAngle(.02) // Ruimte tussen de arcs
     .value(function(d) { // Vormt de data om naar de layout van de pie chart 
         return d.count_download;
     });
```

In the value function `d` is each item in your jsondata.uploads array.

**EDITS**

To access your value on click, it's something like:

```
...
.enter().append('path')
.attr('fill', function(d, i) {
    return colors(i); // Voeg de kleuren (category20c) toe bij alle data: index
})
.each(function(d) { d.outerRadius = outerRadius - 20; })
.attr('d', arc)
.on("click", function(d,i){
   alert(d.data.count_download);
 });
```

Note, untested code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick! 

One more question, if I want to show (the current selected slice) number in text. How can I access that array? I think it would look something like this: 'd.uploads.count_download.value'.